# StrokeTickness

Tags: windows-phone-8

Добрый день !
у меня такая проблема:
делаю проект на Windows Phone 8. Есть Rectangle у которого есть граница (Border или StrokeTickness), к Rectangle-у приклеплена фото (Stretch). теперь когда я увеличиваю толщину бордера, она увеличивается внутрь, за счёт уменьшения фото, оставляя размеры Rectangle прежними.

у меня вопрос такой:

можно ли увеличивать толщину бордера так чтобы она увеличивалась наружу, чтобы сами размеры Rectangle увеличились бы, чтобы фото не уменьшилась и осталась бы неизменным по размеру ???[/B]

Answer (score 1):

Сразу вижу только способ делать поля равные отрицательному значению толщины бордера, можно даже забиндить одно на другое через конвертер

Comment: когда толщину бордера прибавляю отрицательным значением фото внутри Rectangl-a тоже увеличивается, а мне надо чтобы фото не менялось !

Comment: а что значит "забиндить одно на другое через конвертер" ))